# dev/urandom - strerror: file not accessible

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am using google app engine to create an app that accesses the prediction api. I am able to run the app when I update it on the website, however I am not able to run it on localhost:8080.

I am an absolute noob, any help is highly appreciated.

**Here's the error:**

```
<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/dev/urandom'
  args = (13, 'file not accessible')
  errno = 13
  filename = '/dev/urandom'
  message = ''
  strerror = 'file not accessible'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, a place where we welcome questions to any programming related problems that you may have, however, we ask that you first show a genuine attempt towards the solution in which you seek as we will not just give out free code to those who do not try it first themselves. If you have code, please post it so you may be able to receive further assistance. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace and the line of code where the exception is being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

How are you accessing /dev/urandom? That file is not accessible in production and should not be accessible in the dev_appserver. If you want to generate random data, use os.urandom() which will work correctly in both the local and production environments.